# Programmin in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Real simple question. Hope you have something to offer. How can I get the full potential of Illustrator through manipulating it programmatically. Is there some kind of add on or hidden feature? Let's say, for example, I've got a bunch (like a thousand) of vertical line segments of fixed length, and I want the bottoms to stay where they are, but have the tops of each successive line segment to follow a particular curve and to remain vertical all the while. If you don't like the question, and it bothers you that much, then just trash it. I'm really just looking for not only an answer to the example, but also a reference (software, literature, etc.) that might lead me to my dreams of attaining programmatic power in Illustrator. ^_^

Comment: Illustrator as well as other adobe products can be Scripted to perform multiple types of tasks. Just google "Illustrator Scripting"

Comment: then there is the illustrator api.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments Adobe allow [scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html) for Illustrator by exposing an API.

The best thing about the scripting would probably be that it doesn't use some Adobe proprietary language but rather can leverage JavaScript, AppleScript on Mac and VBScript or any other COM enabled programming language on Windows.

Illustrator also has an [SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/sdk.html) but that's more for plugin development, etc.

Comment: Plugin development does not really differ from scripting all that much. Mainly the deal is you get slightly more access and more mature API and its marginally easier to hide what you did, but other then this not much difference. Its just much harder to cope with.